# solve the problem of clicking the web browser button in C #

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I want to click on a button using a web browser.
I focused on the button to make sure I found it.
Focus is done correctly but click is not done

```
        foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
      {
           // MessageBox.Show(el.InnerText.ToString());
            if (el.InnerText.Equals("select Item"))
            {
              //  MessageBox.Show("");
                el.InvokeMember("click");
                el.Focus();
            }
        }
```

and i have html code

```
<button type="button" class="browser button button-hero" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;" id="__wp-uploader-id-1">select Item</button>
```

I Test "Click" "click" "submit" "Submit" is not work :(
What is the problem?

Comment: That Button has an ID, use that: `var button webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("__wp-uploader-id-1"); button?.InvokeMember("click");`. -- You should mention whether the `el.InvokeMember("click");` line is ever reached (have you set a breakpoint there?), where (in which event handler / other method) and when this code is run (are you sure the Document that contains the Button is fully loaded and is not inside the Document of an IFrame?). You should also mention what WebBrowser Control this is (WPF, WinForms) and what its emulation mode (IE7 -/- IE11) is set to.

Comment: WinForms ,  and i sure detect button https://i.imgur.com/OcxEzYa.png i use webbrowser ! I used both ID and class methods, but the problem is that this code does not run on it       ``` el.InvokeMember("click"); ```